# Mogenerator error: skipping entity MyObjectName (NSManagedObject) because it doesn't use a custom subclass.

Tags: xcode, core-data, mogenerator

Why am I seeing the following error when running mogenerator to generator class files for my Core Data model objects?

```
skipping entity MyObjectName (NSManagedObject) because it doesn't use a custom subclass.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Solve this problem by making sure you fill in both the Name and Class fields on the Data Model inspector:

[image: Data Model inspector]

Comment: Nicely illustrated. Was looking at this very field and wondering if that was what was needed :D